# FTP a site from local host to server

Tags: content-management-system, ftp

I know this is a very basic question.
I am new to web programming.Im working with a CMS.My client has asked me to 'FTP' the site that i am manipulating on my local machine, so that he can view the changes too.He also gave a link on cliking which, the site pops up in its original form.I understand that its hosted on a server and i am suposed to make it look like the one i have modified on local.
How do i do this?
using an FTP client.
What about the database?

And also what if something goes wrong during the process?Is it undoable?
I would have done much more research before asking this question, but i have got so little time to figure this out.Thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encourage your client to use scp or sftp instead. It'll encrypt the login and traffic.

Get an FTP program like WSFTP.

What about the database? You need a copy of the database on the server (which is presumably where the link goes).

Get the login/pass from the client.

It's un-doable if you have a copy or backup of the original.

FTP copies files from one machine to another. Sounds like you need to install the CMS on the server.

Need more information: what CMS, is it already on the server, what database?

Comment: a version has been hosted for me to work with.What i need to do is, make this version the same as the one in my local host.

Comment: I guess thats where he ftp comes in.